# Not giving the whole query in logic app when you run query

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, kql, portal, azureportal

If I run a query and list the results then I have to specify the query in the query section. Like I gave my whole query in this section and not just the name that I use in the log analytics workspace.

So I want to run the query without typing the whole query. I want to just give the name of the query.

[image]

Like on the image you can see the query, but could I refer to that with just the name out of the Azure portal from log analytics?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible through logic app's Azure monitor logs connector.

[image]

Taking only the custom query name while executing through these steps will give the below error.

```
{
  "ResultStatus": "BadRequest",
  "Content": {
    "error": {
      "message": "The request had some invalid properties",
      "code": "BadArgumentError",
      "correlationId": "",
      "innererror": {
        "code": "SemanticError",
        "message": "A semantic error occurred.",
        "innererror": {
          "code": "SEM0100",
          "message": "'table' operator: Failed to resolve table expression named 'query7'"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Message": "Failed to get HTTP response because of invalid input (DRAFT, queryData). Bad request input. Please Check user input parameters (query syntax, chart type or other resource input)\r\nclientRequestId: "
}
```

where we can understand that it only takes table to come first. So one way that you can try is to upload the results of the required data to log analytics tables in Json format and then retrieve the data whenever wanted from logic apps.